# Spa app w/ Web API security concern. Can a logged in user with a JWT make random requests to API

Tags: javascript, angular, api, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a security concern about building a SPA application.

What is stopping an end user to make calls to my Web API as long as they have a token?

For example: I am an end user to a Spa web application and I login through the login form. Get access to the JWT token provided to me (assuming this is easy). Then open up postman and try making every call possible putting that token in the header of every request.

I am assuming the only calls I would be able to make are the ones I would be authorized to make through the UI due to Web API authorization.

Is there any type of security out there to prevent this or is it basically just make sure your Web API has proper authorization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely no difference here to regular websites/web applications. **Yes**, anyone can try to make any HTTP calls they wish to your server. That holds for plain websites, jQuery sites, SPA sites, mobile applications or Flash games. Your server needs to do the proper authorisation and validation to ensure the user is allowed to do what they're attempting to do.